# How to add a javascript to my seatle.master

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, javascript

i am working on a team site inside my SharePoint server 2013. I need to add a Java script code to my master page , so that the script will be available to all my SharePoint web pages. but i can not figure out where i should add the script to my master page ? and should i added it to the Seatle.master or other mater pages . any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a JS File und put following line inside the `<head>` element:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="custom.js" runat="server"/>
```

And yes seattle.master is the right place for it, if you want to run your JS Code on non-administrative pages.

To learn how to provide Custom Javascript files to SharePoint have a look here: [more detailed explanation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32984/where-to-put-javascript-files-problem-with-layouts).

Comment: so i create a Script file named "custome.js" and then i upload it to my site assets, or where i should create the custome.js script file ?

Comment: If you only need it in your site collection, you could put it into a document library at the root site collection. For example `http://[host]/Scripts/`. 

But be aware, that other users may access this library.

Another possibility is to place into the file system under `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\`.

For better management you can create a subfolder here to encapsulate your assets.

Comment: i have added <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="custom.js" runat="server"/> after m <head>, and i added the cusotm.js insdie the template\layouts but doing so will show black pages for all my site collection pages ...