# location of the CSS file SharePoint server/ online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, 2016

What's the recommended location to upload CSS and JavaScript file to SharePoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For CSS**, the recommended location is The **Style Library** in the site collection

> **Note**: Use the style library to store style sheets, such as CSS or XSL
>   files. The style sheets in this gallery can be used by this site or
>   any of its sub sites.

**By the way,** the Style Library has checked in/check out, unlike the Site Asset library.

---

**For Javascript**, the Style Library also can be used for this purpose, but it's preferred to put in `_layout` folder in case you have access to deploy it to the servers.

See more at

- [Where to put javascript files, problem with _layouts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32984/where-to-put-javascript-files-problem-with-layouts)
- [Site Assets vs. Style Library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11869/site-assets-vs-style-library)

Comment: Thank you, what about SharePoint online?

Comment: Can't deploy files to _layouts in SPO as you have no access to the servers.  Use Style Library or Site Assets as appropriate instead.

Answer (score 3):

The Site Assets folder usually, though they can live in any document library of your choosing.

The Site Assets folder should already have the correct permissions applied.

Comment: As M.Qassas has said, his is probably a better solution, and I said Site Assets when I meant style library.  :(